# ember data hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

### http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/150/edit

my payload looks like this:

```
var customers = {
  "customers":[
    {"id":3,"name":"Joe","bio":"some tex","contact":"NY"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Rox","bio":"mo' tex","contact":"LA"}
  ]
};

var orders = {
  "orders":[
    {"id":1,"customer":3,"amount":20},
    {"id":2,"customer":3,"amount":60}
  ]
};
```

obviously it wont work, so i have a serialzer http://mozmonkey.com/2013/12/loading-json-with-embedded-records-into-ember-data-1-0-0-beta/ which works fine so far, expet for hasMany relationships.

Is it possible that ember's store automatically detects the relation btw the two models? or it has to be embedded?

Comment: By "payload", you mean, this is what is coming back down from the server, with `var` declarations and all? Anyway, all this stuff already works, why are you re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: oc. without the var, i just pasted it from the JsBin. sorry for the mislead. the code doestn work {{customer.order.amount}} doesnt show up in "Dashboard", only customer.name.